# How to take a subset of data and summarise in r

Tags: data-cleaning

1. I want to take out a subset of data from the data frame according to a column, eg. filter out the rows where fruit is APPLE and work on the subset of this data to produce a summary, plot graphs or simply analyse the subset data as a table.
2. What about a subset of data with fruit being APPLE or MANGO?

```
#>   fruit  price climate   quantity
#> 1 APPLE   20   temperate   100
#> 2 ORANGE  10   temperate   1000
#> 3 APPLE   20   temperate   200
#> 4 APPLE   20   temperate   300
#> 5 MANGO    5   tropical    20
#> 6 MANGO    5   tropical    50
```

Please advise possible ways to do this. Thank you very much.